# What are the best planners for PDDL2.1?

Tags: dsl, modeling, pddl, petri-net

I am working now on my internship with PDDL:
I am struggling to find the appropriate planners for PDDL2.1. The task is to compare different PDDL planners according to the following criterias:

1. version of PDDL.
2. Benchmark.
3. supporting the numeric values.
4. implmented language for each planner.
5. API.

My question is:

**What are the "two" planners to choose according to the description to compare between them in order to make sense?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fun internship! You can pick through these resources*:

- [Documented list of planners](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners)
- [Package to run many of them in a docker container](https://github.com/ai-planning/planutils) ([docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/aiplanning/planutils)) ([list of planners currently supported](https://github.com/AI-Planning/planutils/tree/main/planutils/packages))

OPTIC, ENHSP (3 versions), and SMTPlan would be a good start for 2.1. G'luck!

*: As a disclaimer/disclosure, I'm the maintainer of planutils.

Comment: the [Documented list of planners](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners) is not exhaustive, some planners such as [lilotane](https://github.com/domschrei/lilotane), and [pddl4j](https://github.com/pellierd/pddl4j) for example are not included in the list.

Comment: As I think you've already seen, it's meant to be a collaborative effort. PR's are more than welcome ;).

Answer (score 0):

I am a student working on my master thesis, actively using PDDL 2.1.

The latest planning framework for robotics like 'ROS2_Planning_System' ([Plansys2](https://intelligentroboticslab.gsyc.urjc.es/ros2_planning_system.github.io/design/index.html#planner)) used POPF and TFD planners. These planners can be used in your work. In my opinion, the POPF planner (recent version or update POPF+) is quite suitable for numeric fluents.

I hope this is helpful to you and All the best for your work!